# global variable compiler error

Tags: c, header-files

i have defined some extern variables at a header file named variables.h like so :

```
#ifndef VARIABLES_H
#define VARIABLES_H


extern int var1;
extern int var2;

#endif
```

Then i add it to my source files.

The compiler warns me the following:

```
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘var1’
```

That goes on for every variable and ends at the final variable.

What is the problem?

The error appears at variables.h for every variable.

file.h :

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

void do_sth(void);  

void do_sth_else(void);

#endif
```

file.c :

```
#include "variables.h"

/* Quit */
void do_sth(void) { 
/* do sth */
}

void do_sth_else(void) { 
/* do sth else */
}
```

thats all.
The error is:

```
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘var1’

error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘var2’
```

Comment: Can you post the `.c` file where you include this file and compile?

Comment: The header from your post is fine. The most likely cause is in some other header. My first guess would be that you include another .h file just prior to this one, and in that other .h file you declare a `struct` without a closing semicolon or a curly brace.

Comment: if i delete the .c file which contains the complete functions and replace the function prototypes in the header file with the complete functions it compiles fine.

Comment: do i have to create another file called variables.c ?

Comment: @Nick You need to show more code. Your header is as simple as it gets, and should compile without a problem.

Comment: @Nick No, variables can go in with functions (don't forget to remove `extern` for the definitions, though).

Comment: @Nick Also check your comments to see if your have some unclosed ones of the `/*` kind.

Comment: i updated my post.No comments are unclosed and no semicolons are missing.This thing is starting to drive me crazy thus thinking of adding everything in a single,messy garbage file.

Comment: @Nick: No, there is no reason to do that.  I can guarantee you that header files do indeed work as intended and that the error in fact resides in your code.  How about boiling this down to a minimum reproducible code sample?  The code you posted does not contain the error.

Comment: the code you posted is fully correct, it will even compile and link (only the absence of `main` will get in your way). So the problem is somewhere else. You should probably just start compiling the literal code you presented here and then start adding old functionality in small steps to find the one that breaks it.

Comment: @Nick Are you using `file.h` at all? I do not see you including it. Do you have `main` somewhere? What is your compiler/platform?

Comment: Hung on guys.The whole project is big so i will try to post the whole project.

Comment: @Nick: A *minimum sample* which reproduces the problem is all that is needed (and desired; no one here wants to compile your huge project).  That means take the code you posted here and start adding things in until the problem occurs.  You have now narrowed it down for us and we will be able to point out the problem (or maybe you will!)

Comment: its ok now,i updated the whole code at my first post.i understand the problem i caused but i am afraid of copy theft,i hope you guys understand.

Comment: Run the preprocessor over the file to see what is *really* being passed to the compiler.

Comment: may sound silly but how can i do that?

Comment: With gcc, the `-E` flag runs only the preprocessor.

Comment: IMHO the problem is variables.h if i do not include variables.h at the source file and use local vars instead it works like charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious issue with the headers that you posted is that they are declaring variables of types that may not be in scope. For example, you declare

```
extern GtkLabel *status_label;
```

but there is no

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

at the top of your file. When you include `variables.h` from `main.c`, you should be OK, because `<gtk/gtk.h>` is included ahead of `variables.h`. In all other files you will have a problem, because `GtkLabel` is an unknown type.

To correct this issue, include `<gtk/gtk.h>` at the top of your `variables.h` file. Then create a simple project with just the `variables.h` and a simple `main.c` that includes `variables.h`:

main.c

```
#include "variables.h"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Keep adding the missing headers until this simple `main.c` compiles. Then add your `variables.h` to the real project, and the problem should go away.

Comment: you are correct,cause when i replace gdbouble with double it didnt show an error! :)

Comment: @Nick: You may prefer to simply forward declare `GtkLabel` since you are only using a pointer to it and don't need the actual definition of the type.  In other words, instead of including the header file it resides in, use `class GtkLabel;` (or `struct GtKLabel`, whichever is appropriate) before the type is used.  I like to include as few files as possible in a header as everyone who includes your header gets everything else as well, which may or may not be an issue.

Comment: I'm a bit confused; where do you see `GtkLabel` in Nick's post?  I don't see that at all, nor do I see a definition for `main`...

Comment: @EdS. There was a link to download the entire project at the bottom of the edit #4.